# WidgetKit doesn't work in Simulator on M1, any ideas?

Tags: apple-m1, widgetkit

1. Create a SwiftUI app on an **M1 machine**
2. Run it on simulator
3. Create a Widget Extension target
4. Try to run it in simulator.

I get this error:

```
2021-10-27 15:35:36.959366-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239405] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:36.960137-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239405] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:36.963354-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239405] [default] Failed to find extension point for identifier com.apple.widgetkit-extension: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:36.963702-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239405] [ls] plugin sdk [com.apple.widgetkit-extension] not registered for platform 7
2021-10-27 15:35:37.017589-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:37.017687-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:37.017784-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] [default] Failed to find extension point for identifier com.apple.widgetkit-extension: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
2021-10-27 15:35:37.017850-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] [ls] plugin sdk [com.apple.widgetkit-extension] not registered for platform 7
2021-10-27 15:35:37.028593-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] [default] auxVendorProtocol != nil && auxHostProtocol != nil - /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExtensionFoundation_Sim/ExtensionKit-49/ExtensionFoundation/Source/NSExtension/NSExtensionSupport/EXExtensionContext.m:318: must define both host and vendor aux protocols!
2021-10-27 15:35:37.035140-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] -[_NSXPCDistantObject ___nsx_pingHost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001b093b0
2021-10-27 15:35:37.038047-0300 EmojiWidgetExtension[9771:1239545] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSXPCDistantObject ___nsx_pingHost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001b093b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac03bb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001091edbe7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac12821 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac080bc ___forwarding___ + 1433
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac0a1e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ExtensionFoundation                 0x0000000120466be8 -[EXExtensionContextImplementation _willPerformHostCallback:] + 200
    6   ExtensionFoundation                 0x0000000120476c8f __112-[EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor _beginRequestWithExtensionItems:listenerEndpoint:withContextUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 1106
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f291876 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f292a56 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f29908b _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 718
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f299c31 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f2a46de _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 772
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001157e745d _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001157e642f start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Emoji-crltgdbzqwtpqhddlnwculwplmcq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Emoji-crltgdbzqwtpqhddlnwculwplmcq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSXPCDistantObject ___nsx_pingHost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001b093b0'
_LSContextInitReturningError() failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x8367042c 5a0d3739 c4750e92 134b458d ... 2bd5ba9c f73141f5 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x2bea4bde a7079a50 310364fe 5294f4b1 ... 1a2344cc eb36b0fc }}
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 776.4 - Device: iPhone 12 (8AA03AA6-9F9D-4FBA-A30F-09CEA2CE32D5) - Runtime: iOS 15.0 (19A339) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you make any progress on this, yet?

Comment: It did run in my device, but couldn't use previews, so development was so slow.

Answer (score 5):

In the build settings for your widget target, remove `arm64` from "Excluded Architectures". That fixed it for me.

Can't claim credit; someone mentioned it here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651611?page=2